# Replace NaN with calculated values using a loop

Tags: pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy import rec,nan

df=pd.DataFrame.from_records(rec.array([('Jan-22', 200., 100., 325.,  nan,  nan,  nan),
           ('Feb-22', 210., 101., 328.,  nan,  nan,  nan),
           ('Mar-22', 212., 102., 329.,  nan,  nan,  nan),
           ('Apr-22', 211., 104., 330.,  nan,  nan,  nan),
           ('May-22', 208., 105., 329.,  nan,  nan,  nan),
           ('Jun-22', 215., 107., 330.,  nan,  nan,  nan),
           ('Jul-22', 219., 108., 321.,  nan,  nan,  nan),
           ('Aug-22', 220., 105., 332.,  nan,  nan,  nan),
           ('Sep-22', 222., 111., 335.,  nan,  nan,  nan),
           ('Oct-22', 223., 115., 338.,  nan,  nan,  nan),
           ('Nov-22', 225., 118., 339.,  nan,  nan,  nan),
           ('Dec-22', 230., 122., 341.,  nan,  nan,  nan),
           ('Jan-23', 235., 124., 342., 17.5, 24. ,  5.2),
           ('Feb-23', 236., 126., 348., 12.4, 24.8,  6.1),
           ('Mar-23', 267., 128., 351., 25.9, 25.5,  6.7),
           ('Apr-23', 288., 130., 326., 36.5, 25. , -1.2),
           ('May-23', 299., 132., 359., 43.8, 25.7,  9.1),
           ('Jun-23', 300., 133., 363., 39.5, 24.3, 10. ),
           ('Jul-23',  nan,  nan,  nan, 12. , 11. ,  5. ),
           ('Aug-23',  nan,  nan,  nan, 11. , 12. ,  4. ),
           ('Sep-23',  nan,  nan,  nan, 10. , 11. ,  3. ),
           ('Oct-23',  nan,  nan,  nan,  9. , 13. ,  2. ),
           ('Nov-23',  nan,  nan,  nan,  8. , 14. ,  1. ),
           ('Dec-23',  nan,  nan,  nan,  7. ,  7. ,  4. ),
           ('Jan-24',  nan,  nan,  nan,  6. ,  8. ,  3. ),
           ('Feb-24',  nan,  nan,  nan,  6. ,  7. ,  1. ),
           ('Mar-24',  nan,  nan,  nan,  5. ,  8. ,  0. ),
           ('Apr-24',  nan,  nan,  nan,  4. ,  9. , -5. ),
           ('May-24',  nan,  nan,  nan,  3. , 10. , -5. ),
           ('Jun-24',  nan,  nan,  nan,  4. ,  5. , -4. ),
           ('Jul-24',  nan,  nan,  nan,  5. ,  4. , -2. ),
           ('Aug-24',  nan,  nan,  nan,  6. ,  2. , -1. ),
           ('Sep-24',  nan,  nan,  nan,  7. ,  2. , -4. )],
          dtype=[('date', 'O'), ('series1', '<f8'), ('series2', '<f8'), ('series3', '<f8'), ('series1_yoy', '<f8'), ('series2_yoy', '<f8'), ('series3_yoy', '<f8')]))

df = df.set_index('date')
```

which looks like this (partial screenshot shown):

[image]

Columns series1, series2 and series3 are level values while the corresponding columns with the same name and ending in yoy are the 12-month year over year percent change.

Starting in July 2023 I want to calculate series1, series2 & series3 by taking their values from 12 months ago and applying the provided growth rates with this code:

```
columns_to_process = ['series1','series2','series3']
yoy_columns = ['series1_yoy', 'series2_yoy', 'series3_yoy']

df = df.ffill()

for col, yoy_col in zip(columns_to_process, yoy_columns):
  df[col] = df[col].fillna(df[col].shift(12) * (1+df[yoy_col] / 100))

df
```

The June 2023 values are being extrapolated which is not what I want:

[image]

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: This might help you to find a solution: `df.loc["Jul-23","series1"] =  df[:'Jul-23'].tail(12).head(1)["series1"][0] * (1 + df.loc['Jul-23', "series1_yoy"] / 100)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This limits updates to Jul-23 and later by applying a `datetime` conversion, but I can't confirm whether it's yielding the results you desire. Might be at least a partial solution.

```
import datetime as dt

#Convert to datetime object
df.loc[:, 'date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format="%b-%y")

df = df.set_index('date')

columns_to_process = ['series1','series2','series3']
yoy_columns = ['series1_yoy', 'series2_yoy', 'series3_yoy']

#Limit changes to these indices
idxs = df.index > dt.datetime(2023, 7, 1)

df.loc[idxs, columns_to_process] = \
    df[columns_to_process].shift(12).loc[idxs] * (1+df.loc[idxs, yoy_columns] / 100)

df = df.ffill()
```

Comment: Yes the placement of ffill() should be after the loop as you have it shown.  This fixes the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The extrapolated values are coming from your first `df = df.ffill()` which is an alias for `df.fillna(method='ffill')`. It seems it would be replacing the nan values before your loop comes through looking for nan's. Removing that line seems to fix it.